# Unix permissions issue

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

An executable file has permissions `-rwxrwxr-x` and owner is root. When a non-root user tries to execute the file, I get a permission denied error. What am I not understanding?

Comment: What executable, where is it located?

Comment: It's flex sdk's mxmlc compiler script and located under /opt/flex/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the location of the file?  Is the file in a readable directory?

EDIT: As well what does the file do?  Inside does it execute something else that could have a permission issue?

Comment: ` Inside does it execute something else that could have a permission issue?`


AHA!

Answer (score 1):

Check the filesystem isn't mounted with the `noexec` option, which will override the permissions on the file. Can root execute the file?

Comment: It's in the home directory and root can execute it just fine.
**EDIT**: It's located under `/opt/` my bad

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute you must also be able to read (except for root, who can do anything on plain unix systems)

Comment: But everyone has read permissions here, right?

Comment: yeah right i overlooked that - i really thought only root had 'r'

Answer (score 0):

If it is a script (i.e. uses `#!` on the first line to tell the OS how to run it) check the permissions of the interpreter named there.